# E-Mail in PHP, message threading, regex probably needed

Tags: php, regex, email, email-headers

I'm working on something that logs e-mail messages sent to a certain address. I have a PHP script that puts the info into MySql, which is working fine.

I need to be able to group messages based on the 'conversation' similar to Gmail, and have already read up on this a bit. This doesn't need to be perfect because messages will be manually approved before being shown on the website, and any errors can be corrected then. I just want to make it the least amount of work as possible so that linking a new e-mail to the original should be done automatically.

My understanding is that the `In-Reply-To` header can identify the original message, but that its use is not standard.

I found this on another page:

```
The most common forms of In-Reply-To seemed to be:

31%     NAME's message of TIME <ID@HOST>
22%     <ID@HOST>
9%      <ID@HOST> from NAME at "TIME"
8%      USER's message of TIME <ID@HOST>
7%      USER's message of TIME
6%      Your message of "TIME"
17%     hundreds of other variants (average 0.4% each?)
```

However, this seems to indicate that it's not unreasonable to assume that, if there is an In-Reply-To field, then the first `<>` bracketed text found therein is the Message-ID of the parent message.

So, what is the easiest way to get that value? Is there a regular expression that would let me grab whatever is inside the `<` and `>` if is is available? (According to the post I found, should this be the FIRST value inside a `<` and `>` ?)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just grab the first match in the back-reference:

`<(.+)>`

Explanation:

```
//    Match the character “<” literally «<»
//    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.+)»
//       Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+»
//          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    Match the character “>” literally «>»
```

According to [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you could write something like as follows to accomplish what you want to do (forgive me if this is not valid php):

```
$string ='blah blah blah <ID@HOST>';
preg_match('/<(.+)>/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: How would I use that though, like what PHP command would get mt the values I need in a variable?

Comment: Hey, SO doesn't send notifications very often, just realized this was updated. I checked out your code, and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Will be accepting your answer for this question.